# Please anyone be so kind help! Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this data of year, month, date. I want this to show as year,month,date in Matlab and don't know how to do.

```
X=(2014,01,02 2014,01,03 2014,01,07 2014,01,08 2014,01,09 2014,01,10 2014,01,13 
2014,01,14 2014,01,15 2014,01,16 2014,01,17 2014,01,20 2014,01,21 2014,01,22 
2014,01,23 2014,01,24 2014,01,27 2014,01,28 2014,01,29 2014,01,30 2014,01,31 
2014,02,03 2014,02,04 2014,02,05 2014,02,06 2014,02,07 2014,02,10 2014,02,11 
2014,02,12 2014,02,13 2014,02,14 2014,02,17 2014,02,18 2014,02,19 2014,02,20 
2014,02,21 2014,02,24 2014,02,25 2014,02,26 2014,02,27 2014,02,28 2014,03,03)
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Also keep in mind matlab uses both space ` ` and `,` as delimiters between elements of a matrix - the way you formatted the dates is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to reshape the matrix and use it accordingly. I demonstrate the way to reshape and print all the dates in US (MM/DD/YYYY) format.

```
X=[2014,01,02 2014,01,03 2014,01,07 2014,01,08 2014,01,09 2014,01,10 2014,01,13 2014,01,14 2014,01,15 2014,01,16 2014,01,17 2014,01,20 2014,01,21 2014,01,22 2014,01,23 2014,01,24 2014,01,27 2014,01,28 2014,01,29 2014,01,30 2014,01,31 2014,02,03 2014,02,04 2014,02,05 2014,02,06 2014,02,07 2014,02,10 2014,02,11 2014,02,12 2014,02,13 2014,02,14 2014,02,17 2014,02,18 2014,02,19 2014,02,20 2014,02,21 2014,02,24 2014,02,25 2014,02,26 2014,02,27 2014,02,28 2014,03,03];

X_in_better_format = reshape(X,3,42)';

for it = 1:size(X_in_better_format,1)
sprintf('The date is %d/%d/%d',X_in_better_format(it,2),X_in_better_format(it,3),X_in_better_format(it,1)) %US Format
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I am just beginner in Matlab (specially programing)

Comment: @tutatran, if the answer appropriately answers your question, [consider accepting it by clicking on the tick-mark on the left.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I have tried really few time to click on accept-the answer but it doesn't work. I think maybe i am new member here and the site does not fully activate all the functioning tools for me. Can one pay for this site to be member somehow.